# cannot convert string to char

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, .net-4.0

I got some help on here last night about getting an the index of a collection.  Here is the code I'm using.

```
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 1; i < _prod.ActiveProductItemCollection.Count; i++)
            {

                sb.Append("<script type='text/javascript'>");
                sb.Append("mboxCreate(\"product_productpage_rec{0}\")", i);
                sb.Append("\"entity.id=" + _prodID + "\",");
                sb.Append("\"entity.categoryId=" + _categoryID + "\",");
                sb.Append("\"entity.name=" + _prod.ActiveProductItemCollection[i].Title + "\",");
                sb.Append("\"entity.pageURL=" + Request.Url.ToString() + "\",");
                //The following value has been taken from the productImageControl code behind.
                //Might have to refactor in future as a property of the image control.
                string filename = AppSettingsManager.Current.ProductImagePathLarge + _prod.ActiveProductItemCollection[i].Sku
                    + AppSettingsManager.Current.ProductImageExtension;
                sb.Append("\"entity.thumbnailURL=" + filename + "\",");
                sb.Append("\"entity.inventory=" + _prod.ActiveProductItemCollection.Count + "\",");
                sb.Append("\"entity.value=" + _prod.ActiveProductItemCollection[i].ActualPrice + "\",");
                sb.Append("\"entity.ProductItemID=" + _prod.ActiveProductItemCollection[i].Sku + "\",");
                sb.Append("\"entity.addToCartImg=~/Images/Buttons/btn_AddToCartFlat.gif\");<");
                //The last line has to be /script. < inserted on prev line. do not change it or bad things will happen.            
                sb.Append("/script>");
            }
            this.LiteralMBoxScript.Text = sb.ToString();
```

What I want to do is get the index of the item in the collection after productpage_rec.

So for instance, the first product would generate like

mboxCreate("product_productpage_rec1"

and so on and so forth for each product in the collection.  When I try to build I get the follwong error:

"cannot convert from string to char"

Its tripping up on the product_productpage_rec{0}

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You tried to use `StringBuilder.Append(Char, Int32)` http://bit.ly/cGh8ud overload thats why you get this error. Compiler think its best overload to use instead `Append(String, Int32)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  sb.AppendFormat("mboxCreate(\"product_productpage_rec{0}\")", i);
```

should work

Comment: ahh thank you! it did.  I'll mark as answered as soon as it lets me.  Thanks again, knew it was something small like that.

Answer (score 3):

Change this

```
sb.Append("mboxCreate(\"product_productpage_rec{0}\")", i);
```

To this:

```
sb.AppendFormat("mboxCreate(\"product_productpage_rec{0}\")", i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
sb.Append(String.Format("mboxCreate(\"product_productpage_rec{0}\")", i));
```

Comment: Hmm why the downvote? Its not the best answer but its not blatantly wrong.